# Game Center leaderboards confusion

Tags: ios, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I was wondering if I create a game center leader boards if I could reset all the game scores posted on it? Not remove data during test but after launch.

The reason for me asking this is I was thinking about creating a game where whoever has the highest score by the end of the week gets a bonus of some sort based on my game and then a new competition starts and all the data resets again so new scores can be uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not what they were designed for, no. While it may technically be possible using score deletion through the iTunes Connect interface, I would recommend against it and try to come up with either your own solution or a different third-party service.